How to enable SSL in Rabbitmq
As I got input from security team, I am trying to setup rabbitmq on SSL, for that first I have tried with self-signed certificate and it started to work. Now I am trying with organization actual certificate but some how I am not able to get it work.
Certificate looks like below: 1 is key file in key format. 1 is certificate file in crt format that has following blocks:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

What do I have to pass in rabbitmq configuration?
ssl_options.cacertfile = filename
ssl_options.certfile   = filename
ssl_options.keyfile    = filename

Following is script I am using to connect, whatever I pass I get same error "Unable to get local issuer certificate":
import os
import ssl


class Publisher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rabbitmq_host = 'queue.orgname.com'
        self.rabbitmq_port = 5671
        self.rabbitmq_username = 'username'
        self.rabbitmq_password = 'pw'
        self.connection = None
        self.channel = None

        self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(self.rabbitmq_username, self.rabbitmq_password)
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
        ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile='path to ca certificate file')
        #ssl_context.options = ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2  # optional, to disable older TLS versions
        #ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
        #ssl_context.check_hostname = False
        #ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(self.rabbitmq_host, self.rabbitmq_port, '/', credentials, ssl_options=pika.>
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
def publish(self, queue, payload):
        print(queue)
        try:
            properties = pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2)
            self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key=queue, body=payload, properties=properties)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Couldn't publish {e}")

    def close_connection(self):
        if self.connection.is_open:
            self.connection.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Publisher()
    print(p.channel)
    p.publish('queuename', "hello world")

PS: Above certificate I am using with nginx it is working as expected
